# Proving a polynomial has no rational roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

The polynomial
$$
  f(x)=6x^5+31x^4-29x^3-237x^2+211x-38
$$
has no rational roots since we have divisors of $38$ are $\pm 1,\pm 2, \pm19, \pm38$ and divisors of $6$ are $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3, \pm6$. So, our rational roots can be:
$$
  \pm1,\pm2,\pm19,\pm38,\pm\frac{1}{2},\pm\frac{19}{2},\pm\frac{1}{3},\pm\frac{2}{3},\pm\frac{19}{3},\pm\frac{38}{3},\pm\frac{1}{6},\pm\frac{19}{6}.
$$
But in that list there are no roots of $f(x)$.

My question is the following:

> Can we prove that this polynomial has no rational roots more quickly, without checking all possible candidates above?

Comment: I think it's the best way.

Comment: You could show that the polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$, but I am not sure whether this is easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the quickest way to do it I've been able to find.  Since none of the potential roots have numerators or denominators divisible by $5$, it suffices to show that there are no nonzero roots in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.  But for nonzero $x\in\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, $x^4=1$, so $f(x)$ reduces to just $$x+1+x^3-2x^2+x-3=x^3-2x^2+2x-2.$$  Now you can just plug in $x=\pm1$ and $x=\pm2$ and check that none of them make this expression evaluate to $0$ mod $5$.

Comment: Can you please clarify why it is sufficient to show that over $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: All of the possible roots make sense as elements of $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, and if they were roots then their residues mod $5$ would also be roots mod $5$.  More formally, the possible roots are all elements of $\mathbb{Z}[1/2,1/3]$, and there is a ring-homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[1/2,1/3]\to\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.